# Saving picture result from FBSDKGraphRequest as PFFile

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nsdata

I'm registering my users with Facebook SDK. I'm trying to save users profile picture using `FBSDKGraphRequest`. What I get is the following result:

```
{
    email = "adolfosrs@gmail.com";
    id = 1053423191343936;
    name = "Adolfo Schneider";
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/12144940_1046320742054181_1730939492302855415_n.jpg?oh=bb3a3fa2fb174147ac0a0b41f6dd&oe=56C016A2";
        };
    };
}
```

So I need to save result["picture"] as a `PFFile` on Parse. But I just cant figure out how to do it. I need to somehow convert the result["picture"] to a `NSData` to initialize the `PFFile` and finally save it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized. We must use NSURL and in addition NSData:contentsOfUrl.

```
let pictureData = result["picture"]!!["data"]
let pictureUrl = pictureData!!["url"] as! NSString
let imgURL = NSURL(string: pictureUrl as String)
let imgData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL!)
let imageFile = PFFile(data: imgData!)
```